# how to disable checkbox after due date has passed

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I've this code in php, and it retrieve all the value I've in my database, and I want the user not be able to choose or tamper with the one that has expired date,

please can you help me ?

my code below only show u the word 'Expired' and 'Not Expired' on the web, since I'm only Echoing it.
I want to just disable the check box, and not let the user be able to change anything like the statues or remove the job.

please can you help me ?

```
$result = mysqli_query($dbCIE,$sqlCommand) or die(mysql_error()); 

 echo "<form  action='JobsLists.php' method='post'>";


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {


$exp_date = $row['DueDate'];
$today_date = date('Y/m/d');

$exp=strtotime($exp_date);
$td=strtotime($today_date );

if($td>$exp){
  echo"Expiered";
}else{
  echo"NOT Expiered";
}


    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td> <input type='checkbox' id='myCheck'  name='JobId[]'  value='". $row['JobId'] ."'  /> </td>";
    echo "<td align=center>" . $row['SSU'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align=center>" . $row['JobName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td align=center> " . $row['Description'] . "</td>";


    echo "<td align=center>" . $row['DueDate'] . "</td>";


    echo "<td>"."<select name='JobStatus[".$row['JobId']."]'>";
        if($row['JobStatus'] == "InProgress"){
           echo  "<option value='InProgress' selected>In Progress</option>";  
           echo "<option value='Completed'>Completed</option>";
        } else {
            echo  "<option value='InProgress'>In Progress</option>";  
           echo "<option value='Completed' selected> Completed </option>";


        } 

    echo "</select>" . "</td>"; // need to be worked on.. 
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Hint: If you use [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date formatting (`YYYY-MM-DD`) you can directly compare two dates as strings and they'll sort properly. `Y/m/d` is also sortable but highly non-standard.

Comment: Can you only include the checkbox if the date has not expired?

Comment: I want to show them all, but disable the one who has expired..

Answer (score 1):

Why not just not print it out?

```
if (!$td->exp)
    echo "<td> <input type='checkbox' id='myCheck'  name='JobId[]'  value='". $row['JobId'] ."'  /> </td>";
```

It's better to just not show a button or input than to disable it sometimes. Inputs can be disabled with the DISABLED keyword

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" DISABLED>
```